# how can i maintain consistency within a central database with must be able to be used offline?

Tags: mysql, database, git, ms-access, synchronization

I am planning an application to support reporting on IT-Security Issues for the company i am working with.
A critical requirement is that *working offline must be possible*. Still data should be synchronized with a central (meta)Database.

*So if John woulb be to create a new report within the application whereas Sarah would be to modify some existing content (both working offline simultaneously), is it possible to synchronize John and Sarahs changes, thus pulling in Sarahs modifications into Johns local files and incorporating the new concept john made into Sarahs local files when they both come back online?
Also, if they were to work on the same data, these diffs have to be handled in a way obviously.*

It may be worth noting that the amount of Data types is limited. There are **contexts**, **schemas** and **concepts**.
Concepts are data with *high* volatility. In those, the user is answering a few dozens questions, and a lot of database operations happen. Schemas and context change only very rarely and represent a kind of "question catalogue" for concepts

Here are two possible approaches i thought of:

1. Using MSACCESS / MySQL Backend
2. Designing the frontend with some GUI Library (JavaFX) and using Version control to manage synchronizatin (JGit).

**Which raise the following questions:**

1.Is it possible to write full-qualified sql scripts in Access whilst using a MySQL Backend? Is it possible to archieve the goals i specified with SQL Syntax only? Maybe  INTERSECT, UNION and MINUS statements? It would also be necessary to identify if network connection is active and maybe check privileges inside a folder. is that possible with VBA?

2.Here comes the volatility in handy. i thought of storing contexts and schmemas on windows network drives and not in a database with the concepts.
Since these files change rarely(and do not contain too much metadata), it would suffice to keep track of changes simply by comparing the lists of available concepts with the momentary working copy. It also would bring access control, because consultants can only see folders of projects they are working on.
What should i do with the concepts ? Is it reasonable to store them locally and synchronize them with a central repository?

I only recently started and therefore am very thankful for any kind of tips and pointers in any direction. Please feel free to ask questions if i have not specified the problem well enough or you need additional info.

Comment: The issue is not so much off line, but the users "create" a report is troubling. You mean users launch a existing report, right? (if you can't answer yes to this, then your design is flawed).

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Thaks for  your comment. Sadly i am not quite sure what you mean by lauching a report. could you maybe specify a bit more? my design propably IS flawed tho :)

Comment: You as the developer will provide the reports required for the application. In other words, you might provide some date filters, and some criteria filters, but you as the developer are the one creating the reports - not the end users.  So I been deploying applications to clients for 20 years and none of my clients EVER needed to modify the reports (so if clients need to modify reports, then something is wrong design wise). So we are talking about sync of data, but not application changes. So you data can be synced say on office 365, but you are the one that rolls out new application updates.

Comment: thanks again @AlbertD.Kallal. a report is part of the workflow here. it is the working data, not part of the software version. also i am developing for a highly connected team which wishes to create and modify metadata like reports, templates etc.

Comment: My only point is like any software, you going to over time release new versions of that software. So bug fixes, new forms, new code, new reports etc. will be part of the new version. And rolling out your next great version means their existing version of their software will be overwritten. This works just like all desktop software when new versions are deployed. So your software should be a compiled accDE, and this means end users can no more modify your application then say an Accounting package, or the code to your word processing package gets overwritten when you deploy your v-next version.